# How to set graph position to absolute?

Tags: css-position

I have to put the container content (graph itself) to absolute position - I guess?, cause the drop down menu is covered by graph when pulled down.
Please check demo on https://www.magicnumbers.hr/meteoinfo/index.php?aPageLocation=grad and set window width < 1500 pxls.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the position from your container content (graph itself) and,
Replace your css for the header to same as below:

```
.header {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 90px !important;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```